# Type for arbitrary unquoted property names in TypeScript object?

Tags: typescript

I would like to be able to refer to a value in an object/dictionary as `myDictionary.SOME_VALUE`. Can this be done in a way which doesn't require me to specify a type for the object which lists every property value in advance? For instance, if this were a dictionary with string keys, I know that the syntax is

```
var myDictionary : {[id:string]:number} = {'a':1, 'b':2}
```

Is there a way to define a type which allows me to do the following

```
var myDictionary = {a:1, b:2}
```

for arbitrary unquoted property names, without needing an explicit interface/type-definition (ex: `type myDictType = {a:number, b:number}`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var myDictionary : {[id:string]:number} = {a:1, b:2} compiles just fine.
```

But

`myDictionary.a`  doesn't, because the typescript creators wanted dictionary access to really *look* like you're using a dynamic key.

The only type that will let you access arbitrary properties without the bracket notation... is `any` unfortunately.

Comment: Note: With TS 2.1, you can also use Record<string, number>, even though Records were meant to have a more precise set of keys, it can be handy and is easier to read.